# Assigning Letters To variable

Tags: python, variables, variable-assignment, letter

This is the code i have made and whatever the score is the output is always "Grade: ", I want it to output a letter equevalent but it will not. I have tried using commas but nothing seems to work. I have tied looking around but cannot find a answer to my problem.

```
score = input
grade = ""

if score == "5":
    grade == "A"

if score == "4":
    grade == "B"

if score == "3":
    grade == "C"

if score == "2":
    grade == "D"

if score == "1":
    grade = "E"

if score == "0":
    grade == "F"

print("Grade:" + grade)
```

Comment: Is `input` and therefore `score` actually an int and not a string? So should be `score == 5` not `score == "5"`? Sorry for the guessing, but without an [mcve] that's all I can do.

Comment: What happens when you start with `score = "5"`?

Comment: @StefanPochmann No. Where is `input` set in the example? It isn't complete.

Comment: @StefanPochmann `input` here looks like a variable. Is it supposed to be the built-in function?

Comment: @StefanPochmann Lol. It appears the it was mcve after all and what I thought was a missing variable assignment was a built-in function not being called. My mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to :

1- use one operator `=` to assign.

2- Assign a value to `score` via `input()`

```
score = input("enter the score (0-5):")
grade = ""

if score == "5":
    grade = "A"

if score == "4":
    grade = "B"

if score == "3":
    grade = "C"

if score == "2":
    grade = "D"

if score == "1":
    grade = "E"

if score == "0":
    grade = "F"

print("Grade:" + grade)
```

Comment: Small details make a difference! That's why I'm not too fond of the 6-character edit limit.

Answer (score 2):

Assignment uses a single equal sign, comparison uses two.

(When you're assigning the variable, only use one equal sign)

Comment: that doesn't work i have tried, but thanks for trying to help

Comment: I'm assuming you're setting an input variable somewhere. You do need to change what I stated, though. It won't work otherwise :)

Comment: Are you setting the input variable? If you are, everything should work.

Comment: yes i am for example if i enter "1" as the score the output is "Grade: "